# WebView scrolling issue in android?

Tags: android, webview, scroll

I have tried many options but my webview does not scrolls vertically as it scrolls fine horizontally. I have added webview in my android app to show some web content in the app. The content is just text. But it is more than the height of the webview so I want to provide the facility to the user to scroll it to watch the next page content. But webview doesnt scrolls horizontally.

Here is the xml and I am juss loading the html string in it.

```
<WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
```

Please help me out and provide the best solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should put some code as well how you are using web view , so someone could help you out

Comment: @AviKumarManku Now u can see the xml of the webview and I am just loading the XML string in it. I am able to scroll it through phone keypad but not by touch.

Comment: @sanchitsingh Are you using webview in ScrollView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I wrongly put the `webview` inside the `scrollview`. So it stops vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

@sanchitsingh

If you are using webview in side Scrollview then you have problem with scrolling 
vertically because scrollview scroll vertically and webview also have its own scrollbars to
scroll horizontally and vertically , and when you use webview in scrollview then Device/OS 
not recognize which view to scroll so it can't scroll your webview

Comment: I believe that scroll view scrolls only when its content goes out of its height.

Comment: Then check what you have loading in webview that goes out of screen height or not

Comment: I cant show you the code. But scroll view always scroll when it content goes out of its height. I want to scroll webview only. In my scrollview there are other controls are also added of the page. It scrolls when keyboard appears.

Comment: what you have load in your webview wesite/otherdata ?

Comment: a simple html string, with no images no links. Only text.

Comment: does that string height goes over webview height ?

Answer (score 1):

How long is the file to be displayed? If it just contains Text, what is the probability that the text got wrapped and hence, fitted properly width wise. So, it didn't need any vertical scrolling at all!