# How to display multiple lines of text with scrolling in android?

Tags: android, scroll, textview, android-edittext

I want to display multiple lines of text in my application in particular range such that user can scroll to view other lines. I have tried `EditText`, but it generates keyboard on top of it and doesn't scroll properly. Then I tried `TextView`, it also does not scroll the text properly as I wanted.

Is there any other option available? If No, then how to scroll the text vertically in `TextView` or `EditText`? I want to scroll the text on drag as in `WebView`. NOT auto scroll.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question right, but what’s about just using a ScrollView and put a normal TextView in it? Or Using Multiline Text?

Comment: With textview not working properly means ?

Comment: It means with textview, I am not able to scroll the text.

Comment: I mean I am able to scroll it with phone keypad, but not by touch.

Comment: i don't understand what do u want. plz explain

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can limit the Height of `TextView` to match the number of lines you user wants to see, then simply put your `TextView` in a `ScrollView`

I had done a simple example to demonstrate this...

```
<ScrollView android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It is scrolling the whole textview. Not its content.

Comment: what is your content? Text isnt it? It scrolls the content not the TextView, as its Height is fixed...

If this is not the answer you wanted, then please elaborate on what you want to achieve, from what I understood from your question is that you want to scroll text inside your TextView.. Is that right?

Comment: It is scrolling through keypad but not by touch.

Comment: well if it scrolls through keypad then it has to scroll via screen touch, it scrolls in my device..

Answer (score 3):

Check below code

```
   <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
    />
```

Comment: Ok now keyboard problem is solved but scrolling issue is still remaining.

Comment: It is scrolling through phone keyboard but not by touch as the page scrolls.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create multiline text view with scroll view. I used the following code in your application:

```
Txt_VistaRecetasola =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_vistarectsola);        
Txt_VistaRecetasola.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
Txt_VistaRecetasola.setScrollBarStyle(0x03000000);
Txt_VistaRecetasola.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
Txt_VistaRecetasola.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
```

Comment: Same issue as it was with other's answer. I am able to scroll with phone keypad(down and up key) but not by touch

Answer (score 0):

Try using Edittext with making it un editable, so in this case it wont allow keyboard to popup.

Answer (score -1):

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` in your Manifest file in the activity where you have your EditText.

Comment: My motive is not to hide the keyboard. My motive is to show multiple lines of text with scrolling in it. Please tell me the way for it.

Comment: in your XML layout, add a WebView. Then you can just write `mWebView.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");` and display your text

Comment: Ok then tell me how to scroll webview by touch. You can answer it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138547/webview-scrolling-issue-in-android

Comment: Doesn't WebView has it's inbuilt property to scroll?