# enabling scrolling for textview

Tags: android

I have a following xml for my activity.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Activity1" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/titleStoryRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_weight="@string/titleWeight"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleStory"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentTextViewLayout"
    android:layout_weight="@string/contentTextViewWeight"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewStory1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footerStoryRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_weight="@string/footerWeight"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPrevious"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:onClick="loadPrevious"
        android:text="@string/stringButtonPrevious"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="loadNext"
        android:text="@string/stringButtonNext"/>
```

Here I am loading my Textview (@+id/textViewStory1) dynamically from my code with some text. The problem is that during loading, few lines go beyond the screen. I am planning to enable scrolling so as user can scroll down to view those missing lines. But the scrolling should only be limited till the last line and not beyond. Any suggestion on how can I set that?

Answer (score 1):

Set these settings for your textview:

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"

android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

You can then set it to be scrollable in java:

```
TextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: the problem in the solution you have proposed is that I need to limit the lines to a static value(AN_INTEGER). My lines are decided at runtime. Hence I cannot put a fixed value beforehane for MaxLines.

Comment: Create a way to adapt your TextView to the changing values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) (official documentation)

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the Height of TextView to match the number of lines you want to see, after that put your TextView in a ScrollView

I had done a simple example to demonstrate this...

```
<ScrollView android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    />
</ScrollView>
```

Observe how I fixed ScrollView's height and matched TextView's height to it.

I had answered this exact question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10140826/892055) , please check for existing answers on SO before asking them again.

Comment: I had seen the similar threads on this topic. The problem however in my case is that the height of my textview will be known at runtime hence I cannot use static xml values for the height as you have suggested. The number of lines on a page can vary.